# How to prevent an errant page break and prevent text from running off the page

Tags: latex

I have an
[oddly forced page break that...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOKqa.png)

[seems to force the rest of the headings and pages off the end of the next page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmowx.png)

What code will force the next heading to continue without a page break? The offending page doesn't really have any code on it aside from section/subsections and citations. So is it possible there is a package conflict? The only errors are overfull/underfull vbox or hbox.

Preamble and main document code is currently as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Protrusion
\usepackage{microtype}

% Header
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{RUNNING HEAD}
\rhead{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

% URLs and PDF
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[bookmarks, colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}, pdftitle=
{PDF Title}, pdfauthor={Author Name}, pdfsubject={Psychology}, 
pdfkeywords={keywords, listed here}, {pdfpagelabels}]{hyperref} 

% graphics
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}

% Title Page
\title{Title}
\author{Author Name}

% APA Style package
\usepackage[tocbib, bibnewpage, nodoi]{apacite}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Alph}
\input{title}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\input{abstract}
\newpage
\input{prob-definition}
\newpage
\input{topic}
\input{topic}
\input{topic}
\input{topic}
\input{topic}
\input{topic}
\input{topic}
\input{topic}
\input{topic of page with errant page break}
\input{page running off the bottom}
\input{topic - missing}
\input{topic - missing}
\input{topic - missing}
\newpage
\input{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Hi! Good that you posted the header but it would be better if you posted the minimal code reproducing the problem (MWE) including `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice from your attached picture that you have a number of sections one after another. The default behavior in latex is to never break between two headings, so the problem is not the preamble you supplied: it is a feature of latex.

Adding text in between headings allows the page  to break 'normally' and if  you need to force a pagebreak you can manually insert `\pagebreak` in between two `\section` commands.

In the following code, we can see an example of this. Uncommenting either of the commented lines causes a pagebreak:

```
\documentclass{article}                                                         

\begin{document}                                                                

\section{Section 1}                                                             
 \vspace{21cm}                                                                  
 \subsection{Subsection 1}                                                      
 \section{Section 2}                                                            
% Your text here.                                                               
% \pagebreak                                                                    
 \subsection{Subsection 2}                                                      
 \subsection{Subsection 3}                                                      
 \subsection{Subsection 4}                                                      

\end{document}
```

There is a very similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16993/how-do-i-force-sections-to-start-on-a-new-page-if-they-dont-fit-on-current-pa), which suggests using the `\Needspace` command before sections that might fall off the bottom of the page.

Comment: Ahhh! That makes sense. Thank you very much!