# Change hanging indentation for LaTeX description environment

Tags: latex

I am using the `memoir` document class for a book.  It formats items in a `description` environment like this:

```
THE TERM has a long definition that may run
      on for quite some time.
```

I would like to reduce the hanging indent for all `description` environments to 2em *without* defining a new environment (so that I don't have to modify any of the `.tex` files I am assembling into a whole).  What commands can I add to my preamble, or what `\renewcommand`s can I use, to do this?  The desired output is:

```
THE TERM has a long definition that may run
  on for quite some time.
```

Answer (score 8):

You can update the `description` environment and insert a new length for the `\leftmargin`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{description}
  \item[THE TERM]
    has a long definition that may run on for quite some time and break into multiple lines.
\end{description}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{description}%
               {\list{}{\leftmargin=10pt % <------- Adjust this length
                        \labelwidth\z@ \itemindent-\leftmargin
                        \let\makelabel\descriptionlabel}}%
               {\endlist}
\makeatother

\lipsum[1]
\begin{description}
  \item[THE TERM]
    has a long definition that may run on for quite some time and break into multiple lines.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Above I change redefine the `descripion` environment using `\renewenvironment` (allowing you to use the same naming scheme) and use a set value for `\leftmargin`. Change this to suit your needs.

Comment: Shouldn't that be moved to TeX.SE?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Indeed. I've already voted-to-close, requesting migration, but these things take time. And on many occasions the vote-to-close turns into full closure without migration (example: [How to prevent an errant page break and prevent text from running off the page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48456392/914686)), since some people just vote to close as off-topic (without suggesting the [tex.se] migration path). I've made a feature request for expediting these things: [What privilege should 30k users get?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252705/168244), but who knows...